# How to acquire the "value" attribute of an <input> element in html？

Tags: javascript

Suppose there is an `<input>` element. When I use jQuery to acquire the attributes of this element, following is my code:

```js
console.log($("#radio").attr("type"));
console.log($("#radio").attr("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="radio" type="radio" value="a" />
```

and the result is:
radio
**undefined**

why can't I acquire the "value" attribute?

Comment: Works just fine

Comment: I converted your code into a (single) live demo (splitting your code across multiple demos while omitting dependencies does not make for useful demos!) and cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try refreshing your browser cache. (Cntrl + F5)

Comment: There's no reason to use `.attr()`; it's `$("#radio").val()` for the value.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use jQuery's `.val()`? My guess if you still have the issue we need to know more details. How is this code called?

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comments to answer for the sake of posting examples

`$("#radio").val()` is the normal way.

Do NOT have TWO radios with the same ID. IDs must be unique

Radios must have the same NAME so a click on one will remove the checked from the other.

You can get the value of the checked named radio  as `$("[name=radio]:checked").val()`

Here I on purpose leave the duplicate IDs and you will see it gets the value of the first only when accessed via ID

It is not possible to get undefined in this setup unless you call the script before the radios exist

You might want to wrap in a load event handler in case the radios are not available in the DOM when your script runs

```js
$(function() { // when page loads
  console.log($("#radio").val())

  console.log($("#radio").attr("value"));

  console.log($("[name=radio]:checked").val())

  $("[name=radio]").on("click", function() {
    console.log(this.value, $(this).val()); // either will work
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="radio" name="radio" type="radio" value="b" />
<input id="radio" name="radio" type="radio" value="a" checked/>
```